# Windows XP on Amazon AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-ami

Is it possible to create a Windows XP instance on aws? Even if it means creating my own AMI, then I'm happy to do so.

I'm looking to offer training and there is a few reasons we require Windows XP, which cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Only Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012. There is no support for consumer desktop Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but not directly. The usual scenario is to run XP virtualised, with it's own network adapter, under a hypervisor. It is being done.